# Why don't show menu item in actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I try to show once menu item in action bar .Now all items showing into the menu.But I want once items showing out of menu in action bar .

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.nabege.Show_subject_Activity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_us"
        android:title="@string/about_us"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="@string/help"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:title="@string/setting"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/collectionName"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

In this case I set the title of item via programing.
I want my menu like this image:
[image]

Comment: the <item> with which you are using app:showAsAction="always", place it in first position in menu.xml and use app:showAsAction="never" to rest of the items..

Comment: Item showing in first position into the menu only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change this line and solved :

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/collectionName"
        android:title=""
        showAsAction="always"/>
```